# Spring Batch: Getting step context in processor for partitioned step

Tags: spring-batch

I'm developing a Spring Batch job that processes multiple input files in parallel using a MultiResourcePartitioner.  In the ItemProcessor I need to get the number of records in the current input file.  I get the current file name from the step context and read the number of lines in the file:

```
StepSynchronizationManager.register(stepExecution);
StepContext stepContext = StepSynchronizationManager.getContext();
StepSynchronizationManager.close();
log.trace("stepContext: " + stepContext.getStepExecution().getExecutionContext().entrySet().toString());
...
UrlResource currentFile = new UrlResource(stepContext.getStepExecution().getExecutionContext().getString("fileName"));
```

This all seems to work but I'm getting exceptions when accessing the step context from the processor threads:

```
2013-05-15 11:44:35,178 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep] <taskExecutor-3> - Rollback for RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.processor': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
2013-05-15 11:44:35,194 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] <taskExecutor-3> - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2013-05-15 11:44:35,194 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] <taskExecutor-3> - Handling exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException, caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.processor': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
2013-05-15 11:44:35,194 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] <taskExecutor-3> - Handling fatal exception explicitly (rethrowing first of 1): org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.processor': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
2013-05-15 11:44:35,210 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] <taskExecutor-3> - Encountered an error executing the step
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.processor': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:182)
    at $Proxy14.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:125)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:291)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:190)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:74)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:120)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.getContext(StepScope.java:197)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:327)
    ... 24 more
```

Is there a way to get the current input file name from the processor of a partitioned job?

Here is the relevant config:

```
<batch:job id="acct">
    <batch:step id="init" parent="abstractStep" next="processStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="fileDeleteTasklet" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="processStep">
        <batch:partition step="processInput" partitioner="partitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="2" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<batch:step id="processInput">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="reader" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="3">
            <batch:streams>
                <batch:stream ref="reader"/>
                <batch:stream ref="flatFileItemWriter"/>
            </batch:streams>
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="partitioner" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner" scope="step">
    <property name="keyName" value="fileName"/>
    <property name="resources" value="file:#{jobParameters['inputFilePattern']}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
</bean>

<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fileName]}" /> 
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="recordType,reserved,aCode,bCode,acctNumber,idType,cCode" />
                    <property name="columns" value="1,2,3-6,7-9,10-15,16,17-19" />
                    <property name="strict" value="false" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="com.example.batch.acct.AcctInputFieldSetMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="processor" class="com.example.batch.acct.AcctProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="soapClient"  ref="soapClient" />
    <property name="maxNumIds"   value="${batch.soap.numberOfIds}" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

Comment: what version of Spring and Spring Batch are you using?

Comment: I'm using Spring 3.0.6 and Spring Batch 2.1.9.

Answer (score 1):

Answered on the [Spring Batch forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?137642-Getting-step-context-in-processor-for-partitioned-step&p=445943#post445943):

> The `ItemProcessor` interface does not expose a way to access the
>   `StepContext`, so you need to inject it yourself:
>
> ```
> <bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.myApp.MyItemProcessor" scope="step">
>     <property name="stepContext" value="#{stepExecutionContext}"/>
> </bean>
> ```
>
> Assuming your processor class has an exposed property named
>   `stepContext`.
>
> <sub>-- [Michael Minella](http://www.michaelminella.com/), [Spring Batch Lead](http://forum.spring.io/member/43461-mminella)</sub>

Comment: You may want to accept your answer. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.myApp.MyItemProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="stepContext" value="#{stepExecutionContext}"/>
</bean>
```

In this case when `stepContex` is a type of `org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext`, how suggests name of this property, I am getting exceptions:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'scopedTarget.itemProcessor' defined in
>   class path resource [META-INF/jobs/Job.xml]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap'
>   to required type
>   'org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext' for
>   property 'stepContext'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type
>   'org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext' for
>   property 'stepContext': no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found

I needed to access `jobExecutionId` inside `ItemProcessor`, so I have changed this configuration to:

```
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.myApp.MyItemProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="stepExecution" value="#{stepExecution}"/>
</bean>
```

Property `"stepExecution"` is a type `org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution`